Detailed description of `numpy.linalg.tensorsolve`
The official documentation of numpy.linalg.tensorsolve does not really say much about what the function does. Is there any other description available in addition to the source code? A description with a formula of course would be enough...

It says "Solve the tensor equation a x = b for x." and then goes into details. Can you clarify what specifically you do not understand?

I assume that numpy.linalg.tensorsolve was developed to solve tensor systems of equations, not standard linear (matrix) systems. If this is indeed the case, the documentation should at least have a equation with tensor indices and summations to clearly define what is the tensor equation that is solved.

So I guess with my answer I got your actual intent wrong. When you ask for a "description with a formula" you are not asking for an algorithm to solve the system of equations, but rather for a description of the shapes of the arrays that go in and out of the system, and in which order they are processed, is that correct?

Correct. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, since I found an example in the code that clarifies everything. I was going to add another another answer based on that, but maybe you can just add it to your answer and I'll accept it.

@Arrigo So I'm glad I could still help you in a way. :D I would suggest you add your own answer then and accept it. I will leave mine here anyway in case someone else comes across it and finds it helpful.

Short answer: tensorsolve() solves linear systems of equations using Gaussian elimination, which is realized by LU decomposition. The NumPy code is just a wrapper around the corresponding LAPACK routines.
Long answer
Looking at the source code of numpy.linalg.tensorsolve(), which is linked from tensorsolve()'s documentation (see link under [source] there), you will find that tensorsolve() is just a convenience wrapper function for numpy.linalg.solve() (see line 311 in the source code).
The solve() function, in turn, is just a solver for the linear system of equations Ax = b (or multiple of such systems), where x is unknown.
Actual implementation
If we track the source code a bit further, we end up in numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.cpp, where we can see that the Numpy code, again, is just a wrapper for LAPACK code (which is also mentioned in the documention): The function call_gesv() (lines 1648ff in umath_linalg.cpp), which is called by numpy/linalg/umath_linalg/solve() and numpy/linalg/umath_linalg/solve1() (lines 1774 and 1811 in umath_linalg.cpp), wraps LAPACK's *gesv routines (sgesv for single precision, dgesv for double precision, cgesv and zgesv for complex numbers). The actual LAPACK code and documentation can be found, for example, here for sgesv.
Further reading
The solve() function's documentation lists as a reference for further reading:

G. Strang, Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 2nd Ed., Orlando, FL, Academic Press, Inc., 1980, pg. 22.

Here is a link to a PDF version of Strang's book. Page 22 of the book is page 34 in the PDF. You might want to start reading a few pages earlier, where the section on Gaussian elimination starts.
